# Return all months between this month and specified month

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a table which includes the end dates for many projects, I want to return the dates of all the months between today (current month) and that end date.

The day of the month it returns is irrelevant, so it can simply be the end date minus one month at a time until this month.

Example table:

| Project | End Date |
| --- | --- |
| Proj_A | 2023-03-20 |
| Proj_B | 2023-01-20 |

Desired Output:

| Project | End Date | Preceding Dates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Proj_A | 2023-03-20 | 2022-12-20 |
| Proj_A | 2023-03-20 | 2023-01-20 |
| Proj_A | 2023-03-20 | 2023-02-20 |
| Proj_A | 2023-03-20 | 2023-03-20 |
| Proj_B | 2023-01-20 | 2022-12-20 |
| Proj_B | 2023-01-20 | 2023-01-20 |

Comment: I have *assumed* you are using SQL Server here, however, if you are using a different product that uses SSMS, such as Azure SQL Edge, or Azure Synapse, please [edit] your post to correct the tags.

Comment: A calendar table would likely be invaluable to you. Alternatively, you could use a tally or (a slower) rCTE.

Comment: @Larnu SQL Server is correct thanks. Luckily I do have a calendar table, how would I define the query against that table to return the preceding rows from the specified date and today?

Comment: With the usual `>=` and `<` or `BETWEEN` logic, @BaronG .

Answer (score 1):

One simple example:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [Project] VARCHAR(128)
   ,[End Date] DATE
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Project], [End Date])
VALUES ('Proj_A', '2023-03-20')
      ,('Proj_B', '2023-01-20');

WITH DataSource ([month]) AS 
(
    SELECT [month]
    FROM
    (
        VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)
    ) DS ([month])
)
SELECT DS.[Project]
      ,DS.[End Date]
      ,DATEADD(MONTH, -M.[month], [End Date]) AS [Preceding Dates]
FROM @DataSource DS
CROSS APPLY DataSource M
WHERE SYSDATETIME() < DATEADD(MONTH, -M.[month], [End Date]);
```

[image]

Of course, you need to test and tune depending on your real data.